# Marionette.js Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, marionette

Here is my LayoutView:

```
define(["marionette", "lodash", "text!fonts/template.html",
"fonts/controls/view", "fonts/products/view"],
function(Marionette, _, templateHTML, ControlsView, ProductsView) {
    'use strict';

    var FontsView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({

        regions: {
            controls: '#controls',
            products: '#products-list'
        },

        template: _.template(templateHTML),

        onRender: function() {
            this.getRegion('controls').show(new ControlsView());
            this.getRegion('products').show(new ProductsView());
        }
    });

    return FontsView;

});
```

Here is my ProductsView:

```
define(["marionette", "lodash", "text!fonts/products/template.html",
'fonts/products/item-view', 'fonts/products/collection'],
function(Marionette, _, templateHTML, ProductItemView, ProductsCollection) {
    'use strict';

    var ProductsView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        el: '.items',

        template: _.template(templateHTML),

        childView: ProductItemView,

        initialize: function() {
            this.collection = new ProductsCollection();
        }
    });

    return ProductsView;
});
```

The error (from the console), is occurring on the `this.getRegion('products').show(new ProductsView());`

Comment: I suspect there's no element in the Layoutview's HTML with id `products-list`

Answer (score 4):

Remove `el: '.items',` from the ProductsView and it will work. Marionette is already managing the region and gets confused when el is specified on a child view.